# Place needle in the central base of the speedometer

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position the base of the needle in the center-bottom of the speedometer in one place and not move it.

Please note that I cannot change the HTML except the degree which is `transform: rotate(40deg)`  to say `transform: rotate(-80deg)` but not more. I can however edit the CSS.

```css
.speedometer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 109px;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
.needle {
  width: 25px;
  height: 70px;
  left: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="speedometer" style="background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/LQCv5CR/taxometer.png')"></div>
  <div class="needle" style="background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/JrthWtD/needle.png'); transform: rotate(40deg);"></div>
  <div class="needle" style="background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/JrthWtD/needle.png'); transform: rotate(-80deg);"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want to overlap the two needle bases in the center, bottom?

Comment: Yes but there there's just one needle. I added two just to show that the base of the needle isn't at the same place. Here's a demo at `-64deg`: https://jsfiddle.net/esyq0jc6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make the main element having the speedometer background so the needle are child elemens. Then place them relatively to the speedometer at the bottom and center them horizontally. Finally adjust the transform origin so it's exactly the centre of the circle of the needle.

```css
.speedometer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 109px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url('https://i.ibb.co/LQCv5CR/taxometer.png') center/contain no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}

.needle {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 12px);
  bottom: -6px;
  width: 24px;
  height:78px;
  transform-origin: 50% calc(100% - 12px);
  background: url('https://i.ibb.co/JrthWtD/needle.png') center/contain no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="speedometer" >
  <div class="needle" style=" transform: rotate(40deg);"></div>
  <div class="needle" style=" transform: rotate(10deg);"></div>
  <div class="needle" style=" transform: rotate(-60deg);"></div>
  <div class="needle" style=" transform: rotate(80deg);"></div>
  <div class="needle" style=" transform: rotate(-90deg);"></div>
</div>
```

And since it's about one needle you can optimize like below:

```css
.speedometer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 109px;
  display:inline-block;
  background: url('https://i.ibb.co/LQCv5CR/taxometer.png') center/contain no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}

.speedometer::before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 12px);
  bottom: -6px;
  width: 24px;
  height:78px;
  transform-origin: 50% calc(100% - 12px);
  background: url('https://i.ibb.co/JrthWtD/needle.png') center/contain no-repeat;
  transform:rotate(var(--r,0deg));
  transition:0.8s;
}

.speedometer:hover::before {
  transform:rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="speedometer" style="--r:60deg">
</div>
<div class="speedometer" style="--r:-50deg">
</div>
<div class="speedometer" style="--r:-80deg">
</div>
```

Comment: Since I cannot change the HTML except the degrees, I made changes to your code so it remains the same as my original question. It's working now, thanks to you: https://jsfiddle.net/7j8zrfhn/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to your question (if I understand it right).

Note the few changes. The two needles div are different, they should not be under the same CSS property.

```css
.speedometer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 109px;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
.needle1 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 70px;
  left: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.needle2 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 60px;
  left: 105px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="speedometer" style="background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/LQCv5CR/taxometer.png')"></div>
  <div class="needle1" style="background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/JrthWtD/needle.png'); transform: rotate(40deg);"></div>
  <div class="needle2" style="background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/JrthWtD/needle.png'); transform: rotate(-80deg);"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks however the `40deg` and `-80deg` are system generated. I cannot have a CSS class for -90 to 90 degrees. Demo: `https://jsfiddle.net/esyq0jc6/`

Comment: I see what you are saying now, let me check

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I have resolved this issue now.